# better use of HXT and arrows

Tags: haskell, arrows, hxt

I ve been using hxt with no problem, but there was a problem since the beginning.
See, imagine the following piece of code

```
liftKeys = atTag "myKeys" >>>
   proc e -> do
      key1 <- getAttrValue "name"   -< e
      key2 <- getAttrValue "chance" -< e
      returnA -< (key1, key2)
```

I have used it like that trough many documents to parse, and im before the classic programmig problem, lack of abstraction.

```
<zone id= "greenhill">
  <key name="a" chance = "10" />
  <key name="v"  chance = "10"/>
</zone>
```

I have four (and more coming) files to parse like this example. Some have 2 attributes, others have 5 , someothers 1 etc
I cant be writing different versions of liftKeys according the amount of attributes my file has. The thing is i dont really understand arrows or what im doing u.u
There has to be some fold or something to write more simple code.

Do you know a better use of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a differing number of attributes, then it seems like the most natural solution to construct an arrow from a list of attribute names. However, to do that, we are going to need a small helper function to turn a list of arrows into a single arrow that produces a list.

```
arrowList :: Arrow a => [a b c] -> a b [c]
arrowList []         = arr $ const []
arrowList (a:arrows) = proc b -> do
    c  <- a -< b
    cs <- arrowList arrows -< b
    returnA -< (c:cs)
```

Probably something like this already exists in some arrow utility library, but I wasn't able to find one with a quick search. Here, given a list of arrows `[a b c]`, we merge them into a single arrow by first feeding `b` to the first arrow and then recursively merging the rest of the list and feeding `b` to that merged arrow.

I wrote the above function using the arrow notation to make it easier to explain, but you could implement it simply like this:

```
arrowList :: Arrow a => [a b c] -> a b [c]
arrowList []         = arr $ const []
arrowList (a:arrows) = a &&& arrowList arrows >>> arr (uncurry (:))
```

Now we can implement the `liftKeys` function like this

```
liftKeys :: ArrowXml a => [String] -> a XmlTree [String]
liftKeys keys = atTag "myKeys" >>> arrowList (map getAttrValue keys)
```

And your original example above could be expressed as `liftKeys ["name", "chance"]`.

Comment: Awesome! you helped me a lot! not only by solving my problem, you helped me to understand the use of arrows a bit more!!